# How to label arrays with labels from another array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to Tensorflow and Deep Learning and my first task is to do a binary classification of arrays from greyscale images. My arrays (array_a to array_h) in this code should serve as an example.

I have many arrays (array_a to array_h) with the shape of (300x300) and with zeros and ones. These arrays should be my input as training_data (x_train).
I want to label these arrays with another array (label_array_train) with the shape of (8x1). This array should be my input as y_train or target data.

My idea was to concatenate my arrays into one array with np.concatenate to convert it to a tensor and feed it to my NN. I also use tf.convert_to_tensor on my label_array_train to get another tensor.
I want to label each array with one label from the label_array_train (0 or 1). Arrays with zeros should be labeled with 0 and arrays with ones should be labeled with 1.
I get an error because of my different data-sizes. But i don´t know how to handle or prepare my input-data correctly to get the perfect shape and size of my tran_data and the labels.

I get this error:

```
Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 2400
  y sizes: 8
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
  File "C:\Users\Niklas\Desktop\Python\Versuch 3.py", line 94, in <module>
    model.fit(train_data,...
```

### my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, AvgPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
```

### my training arrays with zeros and ones in shape of 300,300

```
array_a= np.zeros((300,300))
array_b= np.ones((300,300))
array_c= np.ones((300,300))
array_d= np.zeros((300,300))
array_e= np.zeros((300,300))
array_f= np.zeros((300,300))
array_g= np.zeros((300,300))
array_h= np.ones((300,300))
```

### my array for labeling all arrays of the train_data

```
label_array_train = np.array([0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1], dtype = np.float)
```

### Concatenate all arrays into one

```
train_array = np.concatenate((array_a,array_b,array_c,array_d,array_e,array_f,array_g,array_h), axis=0)
```

### transform it to a tensor for compatibility with Tensorflow

```
train_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_array, np.float32)

labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(label_array_train, np.float32)
```

### my model

```
model = Sequential([Conv2D(filters= 32, kernel_size= (3, 3), activation= 'relu', input_shape = (300,300,1)),
                            AvgPool2D(2, 2),
                            Conv2D(filters= 32, kernel_size= (3, 3), activation= 'relu'),
                            AvgPool2D(2, 2),
                            Conv2D(filters= 64, kernel_size= (3, 3), activation= 'relu'),
                            AvgPool2D(2, 2),
                            Conv2D(filters= 64, kernel_size= (3, 3), activation= 'relu'),
                            AvgPool2D(2, 2),
                            Flatten(),
                            Dense(units= 512, activation= 'relu'),
                            Dense(units= 1, activation= 'sigmoid')])


model.compile(optimizer=Adam (learning_rate= 0.0005),
                    loss= 'binary_crossentropy',
                    metrics= ['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_data,
         labels,
          epochs=5,
          verbose=1)
```

Shape of my training_data with print(train_array):

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]], shape=(2400, 300), dtype=float32)
```

Shape of my labels with print(labels):

```
tf.Tensor([0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.], shape=(8,), dtype=float32)
```

I hope someone can help me and show my mistakes in my code or show me how to do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.stack` instead of `np.concatenate` and everything should work:

```
train_array = np.stack((array_a,array_b,array_c,array_d,array_e,array_f,array_g,array_h), axis=0)
print(train_array.shape)
# (8, 300, 300)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categoritcal
...
model.fit(train_data,
         to_categorical(labels),
          epochs=5,
          verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

the `X` shape is the problem. You have to initialize arrays as:

```
array_a= np.zeros((1,300,300))
array_b= np.ones((1,300,300))
array_c= np.ones((1,300,300))
array_d= np.zeros((1,300,300))
array_e= np.zeros((1,300,300))
array_f= np.zeros((1,300,300))
array_g= np.zeros((1,300,300))
array_h= np.ones((1,300,300))*
```